# A finite dimensional subspace of a Frechet space like $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is normable?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis

The space of smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}$, denoted as $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, is a Frechet space whose topology is defined by uniform convergence of all partial derivatives on compact subsets.

Since it is also known to be separable, we can find a countable dense subset $\{f_n \} \subset C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. Choose finitely many elements $f_{n_1}, \cdots, f_{n_m}$ from this dense subset $\{f_n \}$ and let
\begin{equation}
V:=\langle f_{n_1}, \cdots, f_{n_m} \rangle
\end{equation}
be the linear subspace of $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ spanned by $ f_{n_1}, \cdots, f_{n_m}$. Then, $V$ is of course finite dimensional and thus a closed subspace of $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$.

That is, $V$ itself is a Frechet space with the subspace topology inherited from $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$.

However, is this Frechet topology on $V$ identical to the canonical norm topology defined on any $m-$dimensional vector space? $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is known to be non-normable, so I am quite confused about this subtlety regarding finite dimensioanl subspaces..

Could anyone please clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a finite dimensional vector space $V$, there is a unique Hausdorff topology that turns $V$ into a topological vector space. In particular, since the Frechet topology and the topology arising from a choice of norm both induce such a structure, on your space $V$, they coincide.

This is not a contradiction since there is no good way to pass from the existence of norm topologies on each finite dimensional subspaces to a norm topology on the full space.

Comment: I see. Could you let me know any reference that contains your statement about unique Hausdorff topology on finite dimensional vector space?

Comment: I think i recall the book "topological vector spaces, distributions and kernels" by Treves having this result in the section on finite dimensional hausdorff spaces